# How to deal with a frank speaking and overthinking guy

Tags: friends, conflict-aversion, awkward-situations

I am hanging with a group of friends all around 22 - 23 years old . One of us is sometimes having some anger and sadness at mixed times. It makes the group feel weird.

To detail these crises: he could get upset about someone for a petty reason, and starts speaking roughly and even sometimes insulting people. It makes us feel weird, but none of us are confrontation types of people.

Now the main problem is that only a few member of the group are supporting these crises. I had a problem with that, but I let it go. Some people of the group with background went deeper in the issue.

Another time the problem was that he was in trouble with people in the group and make it known to the one who is the best of them, but was also handling personal issues at that moment. With the same problem as the guy, I was not a help in reducing his resentment, and now I think I even made it stronger.

Although he is very rough talking, there is no physical violence involved or mentioned.

My question in the end is how should I act with this person?
Should I force myself to be a more confrontational person?

Comment: I am a little confused by your 3rd paragraph. What do you mean by "Some people of the group with background went deeper in the issue?" Are these people closer with the individual?

Comment: Is there any way you can be more specific about the circumstances?  Sentences like "Some people of the group with background went deeper in the issue" don't really tell us anything. How did they "go deeper"?